# Word addin trying to show both XML and text but if the text have image the doc File corrupted?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, doc, word-addins

I build word addin that have two check-boxes to swabbing between TEXT view and XML View.
And in the XML viewing I restrict the editing. When the user return  back to TEXT viewing I remove the restriction for editing. 
The code:

```
  private void ShowDocBodyXML_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        var doc = Globals.DLPAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
        doc.Save();
        string fileName = doc.FullName;
        doc.Close();
        using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, true))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = document.MainDocumentPart;
            Body body = mainPart.Document.Body;
            string text = body.InnerXml;
            body.RemoveAllChildren();
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph());
            Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
            run.AppendChild(new Text(text));
        }
        Globals.DLPAddIn.Application.Documents.Open(fileName);
        doc = Globals.DLPAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        doc.Protect(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyReading,
        missing, missing, missing, missing);
        doc.Save();
    }
    private void ShowDocBodyText_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        var doc = Globals.DLPAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        if (doc.ProtectionType != WdProtectionType.wdNoProtection)
            doc.Unprotect(missing);
        doc.Save();
        string fileName = doc.FullName;
        doc.Close();
        using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, true))
        { 
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = document.MainDocumentPart;
            Body body = mainPart.Document.Body;
            string text = body.InnerText;
            body.RemoveAllChildren();
            body.InnerXml = text;
        }
        Globals.DLPAddIn.Application.Documents.Open(fileName);
    }
```

The code is working with out any problem but if the Word Doc have an image when the user trying to return back to TEXT viewing the the code throw exception (***The file was corrupted***) in this code:

```
Globals.DLPAddIn.Application.Documents.Open(fileName);
```

I think when I restrict the editing it remove the image file.
If it's like that how can i solve this problem.

Comment: It's not really possible to be sure what's happening at this remove. I suspect that the problem may lie in how the document content is being changed, not with protecting or not protecting. Images are usually saved as separate resource files within the zip package. Relationships are created and maintained to link the graphics file into the main text. Word may be removing the relationship (for example) when the document is saved again.

Comment: Comparing a copy of the original document with the round-tripped version might reveal where the "disconnect" is happening. Use the "Compare Documents" feature of the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool to inspect where and how the two differ.

Comment: Thanks Cindy Meister you are right. The media folder in  the zip package removed with the relationship that belong to the image inside document.xml.rels file.
And this happen after doc.Protect(..). If I remove doc.Protect(..) it save the doc with out remove the media folder and the relationship.I mean it's work  ok. But if I do doc.Protect(..). It remove the image.
So how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Why do you need to protect the document? If you're over-writing it anyway it doesn't matter what the user does in it? You can also close without saving, if that's a problem. Since this is a VSTO application you can monitor DocumentBeforeSave to prevent the user from saving anything.

Comment: I want to say thanks for your helping.  
The Open XML SDK Productivity Tool it very helpful for me.
I actually do some change in the xml view and i don't want the user to edit the xml text. The user can save the doc as xml view but he can't edit it. And also he can return the doc back to the text view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current approach does not work when there are images or other resources in the document because your strip all images when creating the Word document containing only the XML of the `MainDocumentPart`.

One solution to this is to show the OpenXML in the so-called *Flat OPC* format. This format describes the entire OpenXML (zip) package in a single XML document (without the hierarchical structure of the OpenXML package).

The easiest way to obtain the XML in Flat OPC format is to use the `Document.WordOpenXML` property:

```
var doc = Globals.DLPAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
var xml = doc.WordOpenXML;

var newDoc = Globals.DLPAddIn.Application.Documents.Add();
newDoc.Range.Text = xml
```

Comment: Hi **Dirk Vollmar**  you are right. Thanks for your helping.
I want to asking you. Is it possible to change xml in `Document.WordOpenXML`  I mean change xml of the document using `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word`  library rather than using DocumentFormat.OpenXml library ?

Comment: If you want to manipulate the XML you would typically use the OpenXML SDK (`DocumentFormat.OpenXml`). Using Office interop you can directly modify Word documents using a DOM like approach based on the Word object model.